# Rent a car in LA with insurances

Tags: car-rentals, insurance, los-angeles

I have intention to rent a Mustang in LA , but the thing is, insurances are so expensive and I do not want to be robbed by the renters.

Which insurances should I choose absolutely?

Comment: Does your credit card provide any coverage? Do you tend to be a careful driver? Are you planning any high risk things to do with the car?

Comment: There are many articles online about rental car insurance. Which ones have you read already? See for example http://traveltips.usatoday.com/car-rental-insurance-tips-15661.html , http://www.caranddriver.com/reviews/do-i-need-insurance-to-rent-a-car-info, and http://seattletimes.com/html/travel/2021513427_rentalcarinsurancexml.html to start.